# Cannot get a node pointer to point to another node in a doubly linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I am working on a project that requires me to simulate a list of clients that I can add and remove from both the front and the rear of a line. I've opted to use a doubly-linked list data structure for this and have created two classes, Client and ClientLine to accomplish it. The header for both my classes can be seen below.

```
    class Client
{
public:

//Default constructor.
//This constructor automatically fills the QueryTime private member
//with a random value upon creation.
Client();

//***** setQueryTime *****
//A function to set the QueryTime private member to a specific value.
void setQueryTime(float SetTime);

//***** getQueryTime *****
//A function to get the private member, QueryTime.
float getQueryTime();

private:

//A variable to hold the time it will take the secretary to answer
//the question.
float QueryTime;

}; //class Client


class ClientLine
{
public:

//A node to go into the list of clients.
typedef struct{

    struct clientNode *next; //Points to the next node in the list
    struct clientNode *prev; //Points to the previous node in the list
    Client currentClient; //The client in the current spot in line.
    int clientType; //Tells whether the client is in person or on the phone.

} clientNode;

//Default constructor
//Creates an empty doubly-linked list to represent a
//line of clients (phone and in person).
ClientLine();

//***** isLineEmpty *****
//Boolean function to tell if there is nobody in line.
//The line is empty if listHeader->front == listHeader->rear == NULL.
bool isLineEmpty();

//***** addClientRear *****
//Adds a new client to the rear of the line.
void addClientRear(Client newClient, int clientType);

//***** addClientFront *****
//Adds a new client to the front of the line.
void addClientFront(Client newClient, int clientType);

//***** removeClientRear *****
//Deletes the node at the rear of the list and returns the client from it.
Client removeClientRear();

//***** removeClientFront *****
//Deletes the node at the front of the list and returns the client from it.
Client removeClientFront();

private:

clientNode *front; //Pointer to the front of the list
clientNode *rear; //Pointer to the rear of the list
int listLength; //A variable to hold the length of the list.

}; //class ClientLine
```

In my addClientRear member function, I try to assign the pointers in the new node to point to the previous node in the list as needed using this code:

```
//***** addClientRear *****
//Adds a new client to the rear of the line.
void ClientLine::addClientRear(Client newClient, int clientType){
    //Make a new node to contain the client.
    clientNode *newNode = new clientNode;
    newNode->currentClient = newClient;
    newNode->clientType = clientType;

    //Set the pointers in the new node and list as needed.
    if(isLineEmpty()){
        front = newNode;
        rear = newNode;
        newNode->next = NULL;
        newNode->prev = NULL;
    }

    else{
        newNode->prev = rear;
        newNode->next = NULL;
    }

    listLength += 1; //increase the length of the list by one.
} //addClientRear()
```

However I get an error on the statement newNode->prev = rear that says:

> a value of type "ClientLine::clientNode *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "clientNode *"

I'm not sure why I get this error since I'm trying to assign a pointer value into another pointer. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: In addition to the answer to the immediately asked question, below, the shown insertion logic is slightly broken. The "else" part of the `if` statement forgets to update the `rear` pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two different `clientNode` structure declarations (as the error message indicates). Define your struct the C++ way, not the C way.

```
struct clientNode {
    clientNode *next; //Points to the next node in the list
    clientNode *prev; //Points to the previous node in the list
    Client currentClient; //The client in the current spot in line.
    int clientType; //Tells whether the client is in person or on the phone.
};
```

In case it's not clear, here's your version with some comments

```
typedef struct{

    struct clientNode *next; // this forward declares clientNode
    struct clientNode *prev;
    Client currentClient;
    int clientType;

} clientNode; // this defines ClientLine::clientNode
```

The two declarations are different.

Comment: Thank you! The last couple classes I've taken have been in C so I'm having trouble switching gears back to C++

Comment: @jdmo242 To be honest I'm not sure your version would have been legal in C either.